# Undefined method `bytesize' when using format.js in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a simple form with two field and :remote => true.

My controller looks like this:

```
  def create
@roadmap_item = RoadmapItem.new(params[:roadmap_item])

respond_to do |format|
  if @roadmap_item.save
    format.html { redirect_to @roadmap_item, notice: 'Roadmap item was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @roadmap_item, status: :created, location: @roadmap_item }
    format.js { render js: @roadmap_item, status: :created, location: @roadmap_item, :layout => !request.xhr? }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @roadmap_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    format.js { render js: @roadmap_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

My "create.js.erb" file is empty

If I remove the format.js lines, the object gets created as expected.
If I leave the line as it is, I get the error: `"undefined method 'bytesize' for #<RoadmapItem:0x4061d30>"`

I'm using rails 3.2.8 on Windows 7.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

The stacktrace:

```
[2012-11-08 23:08:31] ERROR NoMethodError: undefined method `bytesize' for #<RoadmapItem:0x4061d30>
C:/devtools/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.8/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:407:in `method_missing'
C:/devtools/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:149:in `method_missing'
C:/devtools/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/utils.rb:281:in `bytesize'
C:/devtools/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/content_length.rb:24:in `block in call'
C:/devtools/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:46:in `each'
C:/devtools/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:46:in `each'
C:/devtools/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:454:in `each'
C:/devtools/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/body_proxy.rb:27:in `method_missing'
C:/devtools/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/body_proxy.rb:26:in `method_missing'
C:/devtools/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/content_length.rb:24:in `call'
C:/devtools/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in`call'
C:/devtools/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
C:/devtools/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
C:/devtools/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/devtools/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Please show the full trace for this issue. A one-line error message is not sufficient to be able to debug this issue.

Comment: Thank's for the comment. I've added the stacktrace to my question.